# data cannot reach to custom listview in AsynTask class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I cannot set data to custom listview..

Tutorial link is [learn2crack](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)

Tutorial is ok itself..When I combine with my code, data cannot reach to listview..

Firstly,

**MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,OnPageChangeListener**..
and I'll show code from

**MyPageAdapter extends PageAdapter** .. I'll left some codes because code is too long to post and codes may be confused to see..If needed,I will modify it..

Please check my code..

MainTabActivity.java

```
public class MainTabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,OnPageChangeListener{
    TextView txtGoldDate, txtGoldTime, txtGoldPrice;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private TabHost host;
    private ViewPager pager;

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        acquireId();

        host.setup();

        TabSpec tab1 = host.newTabSpec("Tab1");

        tab1.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mygold));

        tab1.setContent(R.id.Tab1);

        TabSpec tab2 = host.newTabSpec("Tab2");
        tab2.setIndicator("", getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mycurrency2));

        tab2.setContent(R.id.Tab2);

        TabSpec tab3 = host.newTabSpec("Tab3");
        tab3.setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myfinalmyanmar));

        tab3.setContent(R.id.Tab3);

        host.addTab(tab1);
        host.addTab(tab2);
        host.addTab(tab3);

        pager.setAdapter(new MyPageAdapter(this));
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        host.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }

    private void acquireId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        host = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        txtGoldDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGoldDate);
        txtGoldTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGoldTime);
        txtGoldPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGoldPrice);

    }

    public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        host.setCurrentTab(pageNumber);

    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Tab ID: " + tabId);

        int pageNumber = 0;
        if (tabId.equals("Tab1")) {
            pageNumber = 0;
        } else if (tabId.equals("Tab2")) {
            pageNumber = 1;
        } else if (tabId.equals("Tab3")) {
            pageNumber = 2;
        }
        pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);
    }
```

MyPageAdapter.java

```
    public class MyPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        ListView myListViewGold;
        LayoutInflater li1;
       Button btnRefreshGold;

        public MyPageAdapter(Context ctx) {

                this.ctx = ctx;
            }


            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            if (position == 1) {

                    btnRefreshGold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {

                             ConnectToServer cNTS;
                            cNTS = new ConnectToServer(myListViewGold,goldValue);
                            cNTS.execute(urlGoldAddress);
                        }
                    });
                    ((ViewPager) container).addView(v1, 0);

                    return v1;
                    }

public void acquireIdAtPageAdapter() {
            // id
            li1 = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v1 = li1.inflate(R.layout.gold_layout, null);
            btnRefreshGold = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshGold);
            myListViewGold = (ListView) v1.findViewById(R.id.myListViewGold);
            txtGoldDate = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtGoldDate);
            txtGoldTime = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtGoldTime);
            txtGoldPrice = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtGoldPrice);

                }
```

ConnectToServer.java

```
    public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask {
                            public ConnectToServer(ListView listview,String[] myArr) {

                        this.myListView = listview;

                        this.myArr=myArr;

                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {


                    addGoldNode(ng, i);

}
                            @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPostExecute(result);    

                        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(ctx,myArr,imageId);         
                        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        Log.i("Arr value at postExecute", myArr[1]+myArr[2]);
                        System.out.println("myListView id onPostExecute"+myListView.getId());


                    };

                    public void addGoldNode(NodeList ng, int i) {

                        Element entry = (Element) ng.item(i);
                        String rawDate = entry.getAttribute("Date");
                        String dateValue[] = rawDate.split(" ");
                        String date = "";
                        String time = "";

                        String priceValue = entry.getAttribute("Value");
                        priceValue += " USD ";
                        if (dateValue.length > 0 && priceValue != null) {
                            date = dateValue[0];
                            time += dateValue[1]+" (UTC)";

                            System.out.println("date " + date);
                            System.out.println("time " + time);

                            System.out.println("priceValue " + priceValue);




                            myArr[1] = date;
                            myArr[2] = time ;
                            myArr[3] = priceValue;

                            System.out.println("Gold Value "+myArr[1] + "  "+myArr[2]+"  "+myArr[3]);



                        }
```

CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private  Context context;
    private  String[] web=new String[6];
    String date;
    private  Integer[] imageId;


    public CustomList(Context context, String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        TextView text3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);


        //TextView textErr=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtError);

        Log.i("Custom List Value ", web[1]+web[2]+web[3]);
        text1.setText(web[1]);
        text2.setText(web[2]);
        text3.setText(web[3]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[0]);
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Please forgive me some curly brackets are missing..I'll show only how I do set data to listview..I'm android newbie..please be patient and teach little to me..
Thanks in advance..

P.S my app overview is I get data from rss and set data to listview..Before I change to custom listview, it's totally work..But I change to custom list, this error occur.

Comment: I set data in onPostExecute()..myArr[] is global in ConnectToServer.java..Is it right concept?

Comment: what is `ctx` in `onPostExecute()` and where this variable is coming from. It should be `Context`, but in constructor i can not see `Context` as parameter.

Comment: I use ConnectToServer as inner class in MainActivity.. class flow is MainActivity(MyPageAdapter,ConnectToServer)..So,MyPageAdapter and ConnectToServer are inner class of MainActivity..ctx is just MainActivity..Sorry, my fault.. Now,I edit my post with MainActivity

Comment: If you are trying to update/refresh the content of listview then use listview.notifyDataSetChange instead of creating new adapter and setting it to listview. Also, before calling notifydatasetChanged make sure, you must update datasource that is backing your adapter

Comment: Sorry,I don't get it..By the way,data are set direct to listview..Data from rss are seen with System.out.println() ..I'm not sure setAdapter in onPostExecute().. please explain me some code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed..Actually, [learn2crack](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html) 
custom list tutorial is not fit with my codes..

So,I change code from [AndroidExample](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)..Now,problems fixed and it's ok with AsyncTask..

Answer (score 0):

write a separate function
ex:

```
public void setMyListAdapter()
// set your adapter over here
```

call this function from onPostExecute()

Comment: sorry, nothing changes..list can't be seen